# python, generate random string in range 01-12

Tags: python, random, python-2.7

I need to generate random string in python, that is in range 01 - 12. The zero has to be there in front, if the number is below 10. So basically I need the function to return something like 05 or 09 or 11. Can I do it somehow using the random class? Or do i just define and array which contains those 12 strings and take it from there by random index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> format(random.randint(1, 12), '02')
'07'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import random
>>> "%02d"%random.randrange(1, 13)
'07'
```

or

```
>>> format(random.randrange(1, 13), '02')
'06'
```

or

```
>>> str(random.randrange(1, 13)).zfill(2)
'12'
```

or

```
>>> '000000000111123456789012'[random.randrange(12)::12]
'04'
```

Comment: That last one is good if you ever find yourself in an obfuscated Python contest. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
print '%02d' % randint(1, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to build the array and using random.choice.

```
random.choice(['0' + str(i) if i<10 else str(i) for i in range(13)])
```